# Algebraic definition of ground state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, representation-theory, ground-state

I'm currently studying arXiv: [1706.09666 [math-ph]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.09666). On page 51, the authors define what is a ground state in the algebraic approach. I quote them below.

> If a state $\omega$ is invariant under a one-parameter group $\lbrace\alpha_t\rbrace_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ of $*$-automorphisms of $\mathscr{A}$, according to Proposition 4.1, the group is implemented in the GNS representation of $\omega$ by a one-parameter group of unitaries $\lbrace U_t\rbrace_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ in $\mathscr{H}_{\omega}$ leaving the cyclic vector $\Omega_{\omega}$ invariant. If $U$ is strongly continuous and it self-adjoint generator $H$ has non-negative spectrum, then $\omega$ is said to be a **ground state** with respect to $\alpha$

I believe I understand this definition, but I can't see how it related to the usual notion of ground state as the state of minimum energy. For example, consider a stationary excited state. As far as I can tell, this state is invariant under time evolution as given by the Hamiltonian, and hence it is $\alpha$-invariant. In its GNS representation, the cyclic vector is kept invariant. Furthermore, for a well-behaved Hamiltonian, the spectrum of $H$ is non-negative. Hence, isn't this excited state also an algebraic ground state? Is this argument correct or am I missing something?

Comment: How is an excited state (i.e. $H | \psi \rangle \neq 0$) possibly be invariant under time evolution, i.e. how can be true that $e^{- i H t} | \psi \rangle = 0$?

Comment: @Prahar The last equation you write doesn't make sense, regardless of psi and H.

Comment: I'd say the basic point is that (i) it leaves the ground state invariant and (ii) the Hamiltonian is positive semi-definite. Thus, the only state which is left invariant for all times is the ground state (and even that only if it has zero energy).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch - my bad, I meant to write $e^{- i H t } | \psi \rangle = | \psi \rangle$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Prahar This modifies the state by a constant phase, which means the expected values are still the same. Hence, in the algebraic approach, the state is still the same, since it is defined by expected values

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I'd agree if we considered states with different phases as being physically different, but a mere constant phase is physically meaningless. Hence, isn't a stationary state always left invariant by time evolution?

Comment: I think "leaving the cyclic vector invariant" refers to a pure state, and leaving the vector itself invariant. But I might be mistaken. (Though, of course ... if it does not make sense for a two-level system, it will not make sense in the general case, and, well, it wouldn't make sense for a two-level system otherwise.) ---  Anyway, one of the authors (VM) is around on PSE, so you can try to ping him.

Comment: @NíckolasAlves - The statement is that the vector itself has to be invariant, NOT invariant up to a phase. You are also assuming that $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian, which is not something I said at all.

Comment: @Prahar The statement is that the *algebraic* state has to be invariant. Algebraic states are defined in terms of expected values, so constant phases don't show up at all. We are not working with vector states.

Comment: @NíckolasAlves A constant phase is as meaningless as a non-negative ground state energy is (as only energy *differences* are measurable). Together, however, these two properties say something meaningful. -- Note that this is not about what is physically meaningful as a quantity, but this is a way to mathematically define a ground state.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a concrete example would help. Consider the $*$-algebra of complex $2\times 2$ matrices $\mathscr A:= \mathrm{Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb C)$, with the star operation given by the conjugate transpose. Let $\{\alpha_t\}$ be the 1-parameter group of automorphisms
$$\alpha_t : \mathscr A \ni \mathbf A \mapsto \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i \epsilon t}} \mathbf A \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-i \epsilon t}}$$

for some $\epsilon > 0$. Let $\omega$ be the state
$$\omega : \pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d} \mapsto d$$

It's easy to see that this state is invariant under the action of the group $\{\alpha_t\}$. To apply the GNS construction, we first compute the subspace $\mathcal S \subset \mathscr A$ such that $\omega(s^\dagger s) = 0$ for all $s\in S$. In this case,
$$\mathcal S = \left\{\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} \in \mathscr A \ \bigg| \ |b|^2 + |d|^2 = 0\right\}$$
which consists of all matrices of the form $\pmatrix{a & 0 \\ c & 0}$.  We then define the Hilbert space $\mathscr H_\omega$ to be the quotient space $\mathscr A / \mathcal S$. Without loss of generality we may write the equivalence classes as
$$\left[\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}\right] = \pmatrix{0 & b \\ 0 & d }  \sim \pmatrix{b\\d}$$
and so $\mathscr A / \mathcal S \simeq \mathbb C^2$. The induced inner product on $\mathscr H_\omega$ is given by
$$\langle [\mathbf u],[\mathbf v]\rangle_{\mathscr H_\omega} := \omega(\mathbf u^\dagger \mathbf v)$$
$$\implies \left< \pmatrix{a\\b},\pmatrix{c\\d}\right>_{\mathscr H_\omega} = a^* c + b^* d$$
reproducing the standard inner product on $\mathbb C^2$.

The representation $\pi_\omega : \mathscr A \rightarrow \mathrm{End}(\mathscr H_\omega)$ is given by $\pi_\omega(\mathbf A): [\mathbf u] \mapsto \big[\mathbf A \mathbf u\big]$. It's not too difficult to see that in our case, $\pi_\omega$ actually leaves the matrix form of the elements of $\mathscr A$ unchanged. Observing that
$$\left[\alpha_t\left(\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\right)\right] = \left[\pmatrix{a&be^{-i\epsilon t}\\ce^{i\epsilon t}&d}\right]\sim \pmatrix{be^{-i\epsilon t} \\ d} $$
we see that at the level of the Hilbert space, the automorphisms $\{\alpha_t\}$ give rise to the unitary operators $U_t = \pmatrix{e^{-i\epsilon t} & 0 \\ 0 & 1} = e^{-i H t}$ with infinitesimal generator $H=\pmatrix{\epsilon & 0 \\ 0 & 0}$. The cyclic vector $\xi_\omega \equiv [\mathbf 1] \sim \pmatrix{0\\1}$ - which we would identify as the state vector corresponding to the (pure) state $\omega$ - is indeed the ground state of $H$.

---

The key step came at the very end, when we noticed how the automorphisms $\alpha_t$ gave rise to the unitary matrices $U_t = e^{-iHt}$. The entire Hilbert space $\mathscr H_\omega$ - including the map $[\cdot]:\mathscr A \rightarrow \mathscr H_\omega$ - are predicated on the choice of $\omega$ in such a way that as long as the spectrum of $H$ is non-negative, $\xi \equiv [\mathbf 1]$ is the lowest "energy" state, i.e. the ground state.

It is a useful and rewarding exercise to prove this more generally - in particular, when it comes to infinite dimensional spaces, when we must be substantially more careful. But the *spirit* of the answer remains the same, even in the face of these mathematical subtleties.

Answer (score -2):

A bound state has negative eigenvalue with potential term, but a strict positive expectation in the free algebra of positive observables, so its not the ground state of the free Heisenberg algebra of observables.

The GNS construction of a representation space of a $\mathit C^*$-algebra is concerned with the fact, firstly to exclude representation spaces by a positive linear functional on selfadjoint elements $\omega(A^* A)\ge 0$ with dimension of the nullspace grater than 1. This works by working with classes mod solutions in the kernel eg in a -Laplacian, as physicists do it by fixing gauges in Maxwell equation, e.g.

In the next step, representation are labeled by the eigenvalues of a set of operators in the center of the algebra, eg $ L^2, L_3 $. If there is a positive operator in the center, it may be the choice to represent the generator of the unitary time translator, because evidently the time evolution leaves the defining algebra invariant.

Only after establishing the representation spaces of the free observable algebra, it can be deformed into an algebra in external fields or inflated into an interaction model over the infinite tensor algebra.